Godot Dragging Input issue
Currently, I am creating a click a sprite game where you click the sprite. Next, you the click another empty area to reposition the sprite. However, when the user holds onto the left mouse button and does not let go, the user is able to drag and bring the sprite to any location continuously. This means that the user is able to drag the sprite instead of just clicking and dropping. I would like to ask how do I prevent the dragging issue.
I tried to handle it by using the input function and adding not event.is_echo() to prevent ongoing dragging but it did not seem to solve my issue. I hope to prevent the dragging and instead have a click and drop.
